# Time series for network matrices?

Tags: forecasting, arima, networks, social-network

Let's say I have two people. Each of whom I create a network matrix for daily for some of their daily habits $(i.e. A, B, C, D)$. I do this for, let's say $60$ days.

[Two People and their daily matrices http://www.chrisjvargo.com/Matrix%20Time%20Series.png](http://www.chrisjvargo.com/Matrix%20Time%20Series.png)

I didn't bother to change the values in the matrices, but let's assume they vary from day to day. At the end of the $60$ days, I want to see if `Person 1's` matrix of daily habits influenced `Person 2's` matrix. If this wasn't a matrix, I'd do something like an ARIMA time series. Is there a way to process matrices and see if `Person 1` predicts Person 2 or vice versa? Open to any statistic/package that might get the job done.

Comment: One possibility: you might stack the values into a vector and use vector autoregressive models (VAR models).

Comment: Link doesn’t work